# Calculating geospatial distance with radians

Tags: language-agnostic, geospatial

I have a method in an API that takes a lat/long coordinate and will find other coordinates within a specified distance.  That distance is in radians.

All the math I do these days deals with accounting or maybe x,y coordinates for laying out UI elements, so I appreciate some help validating these numbers.

Lets ignore people in buildings (altitude) and the fact that the planet isn't perfectly spherical.  It is my understanding that the supplied method is doing the Haversine formula internally but that detail is isolated from me.

I am looking at the [formula for radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian):

> θ = s /r, where θ is the subtended
>   angle in radians, s is arc length, and
>   r is radius

Given the [convenient mean radius of the Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius) of:

> 6371 km
>   (≈3,959 mi)

I have seen other places saying (6378km)

That means 1 radian on Earth is equal to 6371 km in arc length.  That would mean the radian for finding coordinates 1 meter apart would be

( 1 / 6371 ) × 10<sup>-7</sup> 
ie - 1.56961231 × 10<sup>-7</sup>.

Is that right?  If not where is the above incorrect?

Comment: I believe that `( 1 / 6371 ) × 10-7` is incorrect, it should have been `( 1 / 6371 ) × 10-3`, or maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's correct. Although I feel a little shame posting this as an answer :)

Comment: In regards to shame, imagine me coming to terms with asking this question.  It should be basic math, but I had to make sure this was right.  I saw one of the authors saying a radian was like 70 miles and became confused.

Comment: @blu One radian IS one radius (ie 6371 Km)

Comment: Yep that my understanding of θ = s /r.  It seemed really simple to me, but with this new math stuff who knows ;).  I am waiting for someone to come by and third the motion and mark it as answered.

Comment: People ought to +1 the question, rather than the answer, if it was helpful to you.